# Fazer um loop de chamadas assíncronas e processar os dados ao final de todas execuções

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, async

Tenho um método de um *web service* que recebe o IP de um servidor como parâmetro e retorna um `DataSet`. Vários servidores devem ser consultados por esse web service, Uma `List<string>` contém a lista dos IPs. Um loop executa o método, é feito um merge do retorno para um DataSet local e então um `DataGridView` *winforms* é populado com esses dados.

O código que faz isso é simples:

```
    foreach (var server in servers)
    {
        ds.Merge(ws.GetData(server));
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Essa chamada é executada em fila e leva um tempo para terminar, além de travar todo formulário.

Como posso converter esse processo para uma forma assíncrona usando o método `GetDataAsync` com `async` e `Task` para executar todas as chamadas de uma vez e exibir os dados no `DataGridView` ao final?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Faça assim:</s>

```
var tasks = servers.Select(server => ws.GetDataAsync(server)).ToArray();
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
var results = tasks.SelectMany(t => t.Result).ToList();
foreach (var res in results)
    ds.Merge(res);
```

Se o método em que o código existir (e.g. um evento de um controle windows forms) puder ser declarado com `async`, poderia ainda usar `await` e deixar a execução de todo o bloco após o await para quando todos os resultados estiverem prontos:

```
private async Task EventoDoForm(EventArgs e)
{
    var tasks = servers.Select(server => ws.GetDataAsync(server)).ToArray();
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    var results = tasks.SelectMany(t => t.Result).ToList();
    foreach (var res in results)
        ds.Merge(res);
}
```

Assim, o evento não irá travar o form.

Comment: Eu mudava para `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`.

Comment: Se o contexto em que o código for inserido aceitar `await`, então é melhor mesmo. Vou editar para refletir essa possibilidade. Valeu!

Comment: Eu presumi que sim, devido a este comentario: "além de travar todo formulário". Penso que este codigo faca parte de um event handler.

Comment: É verdade... eu entendi (não sei porque) o código estava dentro de um webservice, que iria por sua vez consultar outros webservices externos. =)

Comment: Sim, a ideia é usar a chamada do evento do form com async, segui a ideia e ficou assim:
            `var tasks = servers.Select(server => ws.GetAllMKTAsync(server).ContinueWith(t => {
                lock (ds)
                {
                    ds.Merge(t.Result);
                }
            }));
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`

Comment: usei duas opções além do teu código, o ContinueWith que coloca o processamento junto da task e o lock por causa do multithread

Comment: Não se preocupe com multithread no contexto do windows forms quando estiver usando Tasks, pois o windows forms define um scheduler que roda em sequência, tudo dentro da thread principal, dentro do loop da aplicação.

Comment: No primeiro exemplo, não deveria ser `ToArray`? Não encontro nenhum `WaitAll(List<Task>)` (só `WaitAll(Task[])`)

Comment: @luiscubal: em ambos os casos era pra ser `ToArray`... força do habito usar `ToList`. Corrigido. Obrigado!

Comment: Miguel, é possível (e provável) que as tasks de continuação corram em paralelo.. Assumindo que a estrutura `ds` não é sincronizada, o lock no comentário do @iuristona é necessário.

Comment: Nada garante que as tasks de continuação sejam executadas na thread UI. No entanto, pode-se obter essa garantia ao passar `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` para o método ContinueWith, nesse caso não seria necessário o lock. Acho que este método teria melhor performance.

Comment: @dcastro: você tem razão... eu estava pensando no exemplo usando `await`. Neste caso, a continuação (tudo que vem depois do await) vai rodar no contexto de sincronização do windows-forms.

Comment: Fiz a tentativa com `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` e sem o lock, não tive diferença perceptível, mas vou manter. Tenho atualmente 9 servidores na lista. O processo saiu de ~24 segundos para ~14 segundos. Eu esperava que fosse ficar até mais rápido, sendo que cada chamada leva em média 2,5s.

Comment: @iuristona: No caso, a demora vai ser maior ou igual ao maior tempo entre as chamadas. Ou seja, não terá relação com a média, mas sim com o pior caso entre os webservices.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo sim, era isso q eu esperava. A pior chamada leva 6 segundos. Aparentemente meu web server não está conseguindo rodar todas as chamadas em paralelo. Vou verificar isso mais tarde. Mas o código client ficou OK.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo, a pergunta tem a etiqueta `winforms` pelo que `WaitAll` é muito mau. Devias remover completamente essa opção da tua resposta.

Comment: A partir da framework 4.5 o método `WaitAny`tem uma sobrecarga que recebe um `IEnumerable<Task<TResult>>`. Claro que internamente vai criar o array e chamar a sobrecarga que recebe o array.